# Gradient Boosted Regression - decide number of trees?

Tags: regression, cart, validation, boosting

By adding arbitrarily many trees, seems like the $R^2$ value can be as close to 1.0 as we want.

This doesn't seem correct. How do we determine the optimal number of trees?  Should I use a form of validation?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is your current process? e.g., - you are splitting the data set, using cross validation/Grid search modules

Comment: I am just trying to learn to use them, I don't have much of a process at the moment.

Comment: The reason for R-square close to one is most likely that you are using a toy example or you are over fitting. If you have build ML models before then check this link for xgboost parameter tuning -https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/machine-learning-algorithms/beginners-tutorial-on-xgboost-parameter-tuning-r/tutorial/

Comment: If you are not aware of cross-validation/hyper parameter tuning then look at this - https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6